# Methods of providing custom reports for an asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, reporting-services, reporting, telerik-reporting

In our windows application, we used crystal reports.  If a customer needed a custom report, we could create it and then send them the rpt file.  The customer would then simply add the report file to a custom folder, and could access it directly from our application.

Using a web app, how is this possible.  It seems like anything created, using ssrs, crystal, or even telerik reporting must be embedded.

What are some methods for providing custom reports to users of an asp.net web application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your users need lots of custom reports, just give them access directly to ssrs. you can control security, permissions, and simply upload as many custom reports as they need and the ssrs gui would let them access it

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, the web application is not hosted by us.  We do not have control over their ssrs installation.

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify the question then. So they are hosting your application in their infrastructure? what's to stop you from making an RDL and giving it to them? they could just take it and upload it to their ssrs installation (similar to the current scenario you described of shipping an rpt file).

Comment: I was hoping to find a solution that would allow the users to run reports directly from our application, not in a separate application, such as ssrs.  Our current application uses a runtime version of Crystal, so the user can put them in a folder and run them directly from our app.

Comment: I understand :-) Just to completely run through the possibilities of ssrs for the sake of completeness, you can easily query the list of reports via web service to display in your app (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154699.aspx). Then you can turn around and use the report viewer control to display it in your application (http://odetocode.com/articles/128.aspx). So technically, ssrs can still meet your requirements. Either way you go, good luck :-)

Comment: Thanks for the input Joel.  Those links are going to help me out a lot.  This might be what I need!